# Missing Android version in Visual Studio after installing SDK

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android

So I'm working on an Android application using Xamarin with Visual Studio Community version. The target platform is Android 7.1, however, after installing the SDK for this platform, Visual Studio does not show the option to target this version. I'm wondering if there is a step I'm missing, although the Xamarin instructions say that it should be available after installing.

If you see on this image of the project properties, I can't choose anything other than Android 6.0

[Solution Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqn95.png)

And I've installed the 7.1 SDK from the Android SDK Manager

[Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyfJM.png)

Any extra steps or work arounds that you can think of? Thanks!

Comment: Simple question: Have you made sure that the **Android SDK Location** path at Visual Studio's `Tools` > `Options` > `Xamarin` is the same as shown at the top of the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I hadn't thought of this. I'm not good with relative paths so I'm not sure if these technically match:

SDK path from VS: C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK

SKD path on the Android Manager:
C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MONOFO~1\ANDROID~1